# VS2008: Unit Testing with Code Coverage doesn't work with /CLR

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, clr, c++-cli, code-coverage

I'm trying to set up unit testing with code coverage in VS2008, for a C++/CLI DLL which is compiled with **/clr** (not /clr:safe or /clr:pure - it has to be /clr because it uses MFC).

The unit tests work perfectly but the coverage information only works if I compile with /clr:safe or /clr:pure. For /clr the *Code Coverage Results* window shows the following message:

> Empty results generated: none of the
>   instrumented binary was used. Look at
>   test run details for any
>   instrumentation problems.

I've also tried "[going offroad](http://blogs.msdn.com/ms_joc/articles/406608.aspx)" but when I load the coverage file into VS, it also contains empty results.

Annoyingly I can't find anywhere that specifically says whether Code Coverage works with /CLR, so I just had to try it myself.

If it should work, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

---

[File]->[New]->[Project]
Select *Class Library*, enter *MyProj* as the project name, click OK

Right-click on MyProj project, select [Properties]
Select [Configuration Properties]->[General]
Ensure "Common Language Runtime support" is set to **/CLR**

Add this code to *Class1*:

```
public:
    static int calc() { return 69; }
```

Build solution

[Test]->[New Test]->[Unit Test], click OK, click Create

Add this code to *TestMethod1*:

```
Assert::AreEqual(MyProj::Class1::calc(), 69);
```

Right-click on TestProject1 project, select [References]
Click "Add New Reference"
Select *MyProj* in the "Projects" tab, click OK, click OK again

[Test]->[Edit Test Run Configuration]->[Local Test Run]
Select [Code Coverage]
Check *MyProj.dll*, click Apply, click Close

[Test]->[Run]->[All Tests in Solution]

The *Test Results* window shows TestMethod1 has passed.
The *Code Coverage Results* window shows the following message:

> Empty results generated: none of the
>   instrumented binary was used. Look at
>   test run details for any
>   instrumentation problems.

---

Right-click on MyProj project, select [Properties]
Select [Configuration Properties]->[General]
Change "Common Language Runtime support" to **/CLR:SAFE** or **/CLR:PURE**, click OK

Build solution

[Test]->[Run]->[All Tests In Solution]

The *Test Results* window shows TestMethod1 has passed.
The *Code Coverage Results* window now shows correct coverage information.

Comment: Found on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/e657ea41-e3a4-48b1-9da3-65a2177aeb09 - "The code coverage engine can instrument and collect from both managed and native code." So it seems that it *should* work...

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182534.aspx

1-project must be in debug

2.-in the project properties you must select x 86 platform.

3 Unregister the project being tested in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, I think it all has to be in CLR:Safe project to work. I don't fully understand why, but I'm in the same boat as you.